# Welding steerer tubes

Tags: repair, steel, steerer

I've cut my bike's steel steerer tube too short.  The bike has a fully integrated headset.

I've asked both a neighbour who's an ex Specialized concept (Certini) mechanic now with his own shop (Bristol UK) and has some really nice DH rides and another neighbour who's a coded welder and also has a few very nice DH rides.

The question is "to weld or not to weld" to re-extend the steerer tube to a useful length?

Comment: How much short is too short? How much is above the headset now?

Comment: It's your health you're playing with. If you have insurance, it's probably good idea to ask the insurance company beforehand.

Comment: You've got two skilled welders at hand.  Why don't you ask one of them?

Comment: This site is not like most discussion sites. We focus on questions that have clear, relatively objective answers. The question has a lot of extraneous words that make it hard to follow. "I cut my steel steerer tube too short. Is it possible to weld an extension on to the steerer tube and re-cut it?" would be a much clearer question.

Comment: I am finding a few posts on other forums that suggest this may be possible. However, you should ask if it's more economical to buy a new fork, particularly if you can sell the old one.

Comment: A photo might be helpful to show how short it is.   I'm going to edit this to make it a clear and relevant question.  If I lose something, feel free to revert or edit it back in.   Also, what did the two qualified bike mechs say when they saw what you'd done?

Comment: "Is it possible" and "is it practical" can have a wide difference between the answers

Comment: I'm fully aware of the technical peramitors and safety issues involved , yes I've asked both mechanic and welder (obviously), and I'm perfectly aware of the pros and cons.so many thanks. I was hoping for a cure not a quiz.

Comment: Respectfully, Stack Exchange does work differently from other discussion sites. You do get quizzed a bit, but that's either to help make the question better (clearer, more generally applicable, etc) or because the questions were integral to the answer (e.g. is re-welding or replacing the steerer tube economical compared to replacement). If you were perfectly aware of the pros and cons, then you already knew there was no easy cure. Why, then, did you ask?

Comment: Alternatively, if you wanted a discussion, that could have been done on Reddit (e.g. /r/bicycling or /r/bikewrench), or Velocipede Salon (some framebuilders post there!), or the Paceline Forum. I have experience with the latter two. If you think the reception you got here was salty, then those sites might have been an interesting experience! I think we have a discussion version of this site, but I'm not sure how it works.

Comment: Noone's picking on you.  We are picking on the question with the end-goal of improving it, by drawing out any unstated assumptions.   I note that you have not provided a photo, or any indication of how much is to be added.  If it were 5-10mm then the collective answers might be different to if you have to add a lot more steerer tube.   Most questions can be improved by including relevant details and excluding tangents, (like "I asked others" but leaving out their suggestions)  Remember they've seen the bike, we haven't.  I'll convert this to comments, because its not an answer to the question.

Comment: @WeiwenNg that would be [chat] which can be fast or slow depending on who's awake and timezones.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that it is possible to extend a steel steerer. In [this thread](https://www.velocipedesalon.com/forum/f50/extending-cut-steerer-tube-fork-33253.html) on Velocipede Salon, one person posted a video from a framebuilder, and one other person I assume is a framebuilder also responded that it is possible to weld an extension on to the tube. It may also be possible to replace the steerer entirely.

You should consider if simply buying a new fork would be more economical. Alternatively, depending on how far you cut it, it might be possible to achieve a similar riding position with a riser stem.

Your post mentioned two people with "dh" rides, which I assume means downhill mountain bikes. I am not familiar with welding, but I'd expect that welding your steerer might reduce the steerer's strength. Also, I'd expect that an improper weld would have a stress riser that could eventually break. You would want to confirm if a repair is wise with your friend. Trusting the repair to a framebuilder might be a safer option. And I'd also expect that downhill mountain biking will stress all parts a lot more than road cycling will, so it may be better to just get a new fork after all.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, for steel it's possible and is done sometimes to either repair forks or create extra-long steerers. There are technicalities to it that are best left to a pro framebuilder (which I'm not). From what I understand, in some cases a butt weld may work (I was surprised too but I know of framebuilders who are at least okay with doing extended steerers this way) and I think in the majority of cases doing it with a specially machined internal reinforcing plug down in the thick part of the steerer is preferred. In any case a lot of steps have to be taken to maintain alignment and keep it strong enough (machining the cut ends perfectly square, measuring the IDs of the pieces to join and turning the reinforcing piece to match, etc).

Comment: Concur - an internal reinforcement sleeve is the correct way to do this.  An experienced welder would plug-weld the reinforcement sleeve to one part (ie away from the main weld), perhaps even taking it right through to the underside of the fork crown for access.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the existing great answers.

You also have the option of just replacing the 'uppers' of the fork,
this would be a fraction of the cost of a whole new fork.